# webpack extract-text-webpack-plugin ignoreOrder not working

Tags: css, webpack, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm trying to use [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to generate bundled css file and make it generated in order.

Now, CSS file was generated, but "ignoreOrder" seems not working, the content's order doesn't obey source code's order.

```
//webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const ExtractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: function(getPath) {
        return getPath('css/[name].css');
    },
    allChunks: false
});
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'index': './index.js',
        // ......
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, ((env = 'develop') => {
            let assignRoot = {
                'develop': './develop/bundle/'
                // ......
            };
            return assignRoot[env];
        })(process.env.NODE_ENV))
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window,jQuery=>this.jQuery'
            }, {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            test: /\.css$|\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractSCSS.extract({
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'preprocess-loader',
                        options: {
                            THEME: 'uplantravel'
                        }
                    }
                ],
            })
        }]
    },
    plugins: ExtractSCSS

};
```

And my js imports some scss and js.

```
//index.js
import './@magaele/a.scss';
import './@magaele/b.scss';
import './@magaele/c/css.scss';
//......

import './@magaele/a/module.js';
import './@magaele/b/module.js';
import './@magaele/c/module.js';
//......
```

- webpack version: 3.5.5
- extract-text-webpack-plugin version: 3.10.10